# Adding multiple custom controls

Tags: asp.net, controls

I have a custom control (customContainer) that can hold multiple custom controls of type ConditionControl. When I click a button in my customContainer control I want to add another customControl to my container.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            CustomControlsPanel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
            ConditionControl myCc = (ConditionControl)LoadControl(@"~/ConditionControl.ascx");
            CustomControlsPanel.Controls.Add(myCc);
        }
```

This works only once. So I click it once, it adds a Condition control but then it does not work anymore. How can I fix this ?

Edit: I tried saving the control collection of my panel into a session variable and then using that in order to restore the controls like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Session["controls"] = ConditionControlsPanel.Controls;
            }
            else
            {
                ControlCollection temp = (ControlCollection)Session["controls"];
                ConditionControlsPanel.Controls.Clear();
                foreach (Control ctrl in temp)
                {
                    ConditionControlsPanel.Controls.Add(ctrl);
                }

            }
        }
```

I get an error when I try to add a new control saying `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` when I try to do the foreach

Answer (score -1):

That is because everytime you click on the button, it postbacks, removes the first one and adds the new one. To overcome this, you can either prevent postback(by something like UpdatePanel) or keep the count of the added ConditionControls (like in session) and add controls as many as the counter you keep in session says

Comment: UpdatePanel does not prevent postbacks.

Comment: The thing is those controls that I'm adding can also contain information so if i were to create a number of controls every time i enter the page then I'd have to keep all of that data stored somewhere. There must be something simpler I can do to fix this

Comment: No, it does not. Postbacks will still occur and the page lifecycle will run through. It's just that the lifecycle will occur asynchronously via AJAX, and it will be a partial postback. UpdatePanel is difficult to understand, and you should make sure you have a solid understanding of it before you recommend it to others or try to explain to others how it works.